# How to pass argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**Solved, Yohoo**

I have a dialog plugin, like this

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  click:function(){
    alert(1);
  },
  'class':"dialog"
});
```

Following code is a chunk of main code that loop on options and check if key is a jQuery function and then call it else set it as attribute

```
$.each(options,function(key,val){
   if(key in $.attrFn){
    $('#div')[key](val);    // I want pass arguments to this function
    // equal $('#div').click(function(args){
    //     alert(1);
    // });
    // this is like jQuery ui dialog buttons options
   } else {
    $('#div').attr(key,val);
   }
});
```

I want pass some arguments to the function, but I don't know how??

Example:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  click:function(dialog){
    dialog.disAppear();
  },
  'class':"dialog"
});
```

**Solved**:

```
$.each(v,function(q,w){
    if(q in $.attrFn){
            //console.log(dialog);
            b[q](function(){
                w(dialog);
            });
    } else {
        b.attr(q,w);
    }
});
```

Comment: You want to pass arguments to what function? Please **edit** your question and clarify.

Comment: @jmort253  to $('#div')[q](val); it equal ( $('#div').click(function(pass here){});
)

Comment: Below the question, click **edit**, and then put that in your question. Don't force people trying to help you to read code in comments. It shows a lack of respect for the community of people helping you. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks for doing that :)

Comment: MR OK - Congrats on finding a solution. However, the answer shouldn't go in the body of the question. Next, you should either mark an accepted answer below, or if none of the ones below solve the problem, you should post your solution as an answer to the question and mark it as the actual, accepted answer. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, as long as it's posted as an actual answer. Good luck, and thanks for coming back to follow up with the solution. You've ensured others can benefit as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we Can use JavaScript IIFE to pass arguments, so we can:
i wrapped it to function(){}, to prevent self execution

```
$.each(v,function(q,w){
    if(q in $.attrFn){
        if($.isFunction(w)) {
            b[q](function(e){
                w(e,dialog);
            });
        } else b[q](w);
    } else {
        b.attr(q,w);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of `Dialog` on http://jsfiddle.net/Jams/hcTTH/

There is a question on SO which may suits your requirements here it is [How to pass a parameter to jQuery UI dialog event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930676/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-jquery-ui-dialog-event-handler)

Other one is here

[Passing data to a jQuery UI Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394491/passing-data-to-a-jquery-ui-dialog)

Comment: Then it's a dupe, not an answer.

Comment: @MR.OK: If you can tell us where you want to pass arguments then I can try to give you a proper answer.

Comment: You could of course try elaborating on your answer and including some details that make it more than just a few duplicate links. I personally find the two resources you added to be a lot more complicated than what the op is asking, and I'm sure we all could benefit from a short example perhaps?